# C write file byte by byte using system call

Tags: c, unix

I want to write to a file from a char buffer byte by byte and it is a must that I use the system call write() for this task. I have my code setup like below but it prints the file plus adds garbage. What am I doing wrong?

```
void writeFile(char *fileName) {
    int fd;
    int i = 0;

    if ((fd = open(fileName, O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0777)) >= 0) {

        while (write(fd, buffer+i, 1) == 1)
            i++;

        printf("Success\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `buffer`? How is this code supposed to know when to stop? (You question seems to be something like "Why doesn't my code know when to stop?" Well, where's the code to know when to stop?)

Comment: Looks like you're not checking for the end of the buffer.  Either a count of bytes to write (but then why not write them all in one call?), or a termination flag like '\0' should work.

Comment: @jamesqf This is a school assignment and it is important that I write byte by byte and writing them all at once..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (write(fd, buffer+i, 1) == 1)
```

is a loop that will continue to run as long as the `write` succeeds, and as long as the dereference of `buffer+i` (by `write`) doesn't cause your program to crash.

You need to place a limit somehow on the data you want to write, such as:

```
void writeFile(char *fileName, char *buffer, size_t sz) {
    int fd;
    size_t i = 0;

    if ((fd = open (fileName, O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0777)) < 0)
        return;

    while (i < sz) {
        if (write (fd, buffer+i, 1) != 1) {
            close (fd);
            return;
        }
        i++;
    }

    close (fd);
    printf("Success\n");
}
```

This is still writing the data byte by byte, but with a proper termination condition.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks. If I want to write 256 byte chunks can I do `write (fd, buffer+i, 256)` ?

Comment: @Chani, yes, but then keep in mind you have to increase `i` by 256 each time through the loop and, on the last iteration, you may have _less_ than 256 to go.

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass in or use the buffer's length anywhere, so the write() call is just going to keep accessing memory contents well past the end of the valod buffer until write() fails (which is unlikely to happen soon) or your program hits invalid memory and dies (more likely).

Comment: So if I did `while (write(fd, buffer+i, sizeof(buffer)) == 1)` is it writing byte by byte?